# Windows Shared Folder Verses WCF or TCP Server

Tags: wcf, tcp, directory, shared

I'm building a monitoring system where windows client machines must send results back to a server.
At the moment the server has a shared folder acting as a queue and clients simply copy their results as files into the shared folder for the server to read.
Is there any advantage in doing this using WCF or TCP instead of shared folders? (It doesn't need to work across domains or firewalls)

Rick

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any advantage in doing this

You've got to ask it the other way around. Are there any problems using file shares? If not, it ain't broke, so don't fix it.